# How would I be able to access (click buttons, type text) to Java AWT / Swing Frames from another application?

Tags: java, jvm, awt, jframe

I work with application testing and would like for our integration testcode (written in Java and using among other stuff Selenium Webdriver) to access frames executed in a different JVM (launched by the product we are testing).

I have looked at using FestSwing, but it relies on Java 1.6 and we are forced to use Java 1.5.

Our organization previously used QuickTest Professional but it was too unstable. It had some way of accessing the frames through jvm hooks in the other JVM.

Our product is a web that sometimes uses Java Swing JFrames and AWT Frames.

/Mikael Magnusson.

Comment: Things seems a little unclear to me. Do you want to access frames of a Swing application, or frames of ... say ... a Swing applet ?

Comment: i would like to access frames i guess that they are launched from an applet since it is a web application but i could be wrong. Some of the java code i want to access is launched from jar-files stored locally on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to review this resource: http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools

Comment: None of the testing tools seems to have what I require. None of them can handle cross JVM discovery of frames.